# I want to alert php date as attribute in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, date

I have a piece of code below and purpose is i have php date and i want to match its value in jquery

```
    <?php
$startDate = date("Y-m-d");
$prevDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startDate .' -1 day'));
$secondPrvDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startDate . ' - 2 day'));
?>
```

and jquery code is

```
 <script>
    $(document.body).on('click', '.nbs-flexisel-nav-left', function () {
       alert(<?php echo $startDate; ?>); 
       return false;

    });
    <script>
```

but when it alert it show only 2008 instead of showing previous date to current date

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to but the content of alert between double quotes

```
alert('<?php echo $startDate; ?>');
```

Moreover you have some invalid elements:

> script elements must be closed by their corresponding closing elements

eg:

```
    <script>
    //Your code goes here
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `double` quote to display whole date.

```
alert("<?php echo $startDate;?>");
```

Instead Of

```
alert(<?php echo $startDate;?>);
```

Answer (score 1):

use a quote around php code in alert like

```
alert('<?php echo $startDate; ?>');
```

and keep closing `<script>` tag at the end

```
</script>
```

so full script will be

```
<script>
    $(document.body).on('click', '.nbs-flexisel-nav-left', function () {
       alert('<?php echo $startDate; ?>'); 
       return false;
    });
</script>
```